# Script wont print my echo statement (Also need to suppress the warning)

Tags: bash, scripts, passwd

I am trying to write a very simple shell script in Linux. The Scenario I am trying to achieve is:

Creating an user account and giving it a password internally (No interaction with user allowed for this). Once successful, Just display a success message to the user. None of the rest should be displayed.

On RHEL this turned out to be pretty simple as passwd command accepts the --stdin option which helped me pass the input via Pipe. And I redirected the standard output in a log file. [Not sharing that code as it's tad simple and explained multiple times here for different question on StackExcahnge.]

However, Ubuntu is not accepting the --stdin option for passwd hence I had to use the below method:

```
#!/bin/bash
useradd -m demo &>path/to/logfile.log
passwd demo &>>path/to/logfile.log << EOF
myPasswd
myPasswd
EOF
echo "User demo successfully added to the system."
```

Now The problem here is my output does not print the echo statement and also displays a warning:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ./usercreate.sh 
./usercreate.sh: line 8: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
root@ubuntu:~#
```

instead of my expected one:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ./usercreate.sh 
User demo successfully added to the system.
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Please help me with these two things:

1. Is there a way to suppress that warning for this script only?
2. Why is it not printing my echo statement and how can I print it?

PS: Another way or idea to write this script is also welcome

Thanks

Comment: You should remove a space between `<<` and `EOF` here `<< EOF`

Comment: @KasiyA, that does not seem to work.

Comment: emmm... What about running your script by `bash usercreate.sh` and fix (`<<EOF`)? And what is the **line 8** in your script?

Comment: Line 8 is nothing. Its the last line with no text.
I got the solution. I had a trailing space in front of EOF which was causing the problems. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: As I said in [my first comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/590534/script-wont-print-my-echo-statement-also-need-to-suppress-the-warning#comment820794_590534) :P Also you can quote it by `<< 'EOF'`

Comment: Yes, Only thing was we were looking for a space in wrong place :) The Ending delimiter was the one that was causing the issue. But yes, that tip was definitely helpfull @KasiyA. Thanks (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wile using HEREDOC delimiter, there should not be any lagging or trailing spaces and the delimiter should be the only word on the line. I this example, I had a space after EOF which was causing all the issue. Script is working as expected after removing that lagging space!!

Credit for this answers goes to the user Carlos Campderrós on StackOverflow. Just sharing his answer to my question here

Comment: Also read [Linux Shell script to add a user with a password to the system](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html)

Comment: Yep @KasiyA, had read that. However, that's more of an interactive script